# jQuery if less than 10 do this, else if 0 do this not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm rather new to JavaScript and I'm having a little problem with this if/then/else if statement. I tried a few things below but am stuck. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
if (variant.inventory_management == "shopify" && variant.inventory_policy != "continue") {
    if (variant.inventory_quantity < 10) {
      $lowStockAmount.html('Last few remaining! only ' + variant.inventory_quantity + ' left');
    } else if (variant.inventory_quantity < 1)  {
      $lowStockAmount.html("We're sold out, Don't worry! <a href='#'>click here</a> to be notified when it's back in stock.");
    }
  }
```

I tried == 0 as well but I end up with the same thing: it just shows the last few remaining! only 0 left but if it is 0, I'd like it to show the sold out message.

Comment: You should check variant.inventory_quantity < 1 before variant.inventory_quantity < 10 since even the values < 1 would qualify for < 10

Comment: That's because variant.inventory_quantity < 10 will always return true for 0 as 0 is less than 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified answer to your problem. If the quantity is 0, show the "We're sold out" info. Else, if the quantity is not 0 but less than 10, show the "Last few remaining" info. Otherwise don't show anything.

```
var quantity = 10;

if (quantity === 0) {
    console.log("We're sold out, Don't worry! <a href='#'>click here</a> to be notified when it's back in stock.");
} else if (quantity < 10) {
    console.log('Last few remaining! only ' + quantity + ' left');
}
```

<s>The `quantity == "0"` will not work, because you're comparing a number with a string.</s>

EDIT: `quantity == "0"` will work but is not a proper style of comparing two values.

Comment: Thanks mate, had to make some slight changes but only with the value and how its passed but seems to have worked great! thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually `quantity == "0"` will work since `==` does not check type in contrast to `===`.

Comment: @connexo Yes, you're absolutely right. But this style of coding should not be a habit we should propagate and could cause problems in other circumstances. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Think about the logic as it is right now. If `variant.inventory_quantity` is 0, the "else if" statement will never run, because it will only be checked if `variant.inventory_quantity` is NOT less than 10.

Here's the fix. Change this line:

`if (variant.inventory_quantity < 10) {`

to this:

`if (variant.inventory_quantity < 10 && variant.inventory_quantity > 0) {`

Comment: None of the messages seems to show now for some reason, so anything that is 0 or below to show sold out message and anything below 10 to show last remaining... is the else if wrong maybe?

Comment: Can you paste your new code to confirm there's not a typo?

Comment: I have just changed it again so its now: if (variant.inventory_quantity < 10 && variant.inventory_quantity > 0) {
          $lowStockAmount.html('Last few remaining! only ' + variant.inventory_quantity + ' left');
        } else if (variant.inventory_quantity == "0" || variant.inventory_quantity < 0)  {
          $lowStockAmount.html("We're sold out, Don't worry! <a href='#'>click here</a> to be notified when it's back in stock.");
        }

Comment: weird it does work, if one of the options has a stock more than 10 non of it works, anything over 10 does not need to show anything but when changing option and stock is 10 below etc.. those actions should work.

Comment: But the first option i changed to 20 in stock and as i said, prevented others when selecting the options but if all 3 options are 10 or below it works, when changing the option etc...

Comment: Or you could just change the order of the two conditions

Comment: I guess, so would need to show sold out if 0 or less, under 10 would show last remaining and over 10 would show nothing.... i just tried but 80% works... maybe the conditions i have in currently are conflicting as i added else { $lowStockAmount.html(""); }

Comment: if (variant.inventory_quantity < 10 && variant.inventory_quantity > 0) {
          $lowStockAmount.html('Last few remaining! only ' + variant.inventory_quantity + ' left');
        } else if (variant.inventory_quantity < 0)  {
          $lowStockAmount.html("We're sold out, Don't worry! <a href='#'>click here</a> to be notified when it's back in stock.");
        } else if (variant.inventory_quantity > 10) {
          $lowStockAmount.html("");
        }